# v-for nested array or object

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, v-for

How can I access to those elements with v-for? The only result I got is the whole object.

```
<template>
    <div>   
        <pre>
            <div v-for="item in data" :key="item.id">
                {{ item }}
                <p v-for="foto in item" :key="foto.id">{{ foto }}   
              </p>
            </div>        
        </pre>
</div>
  </template>
  <script setup>
  
  const query = gql`query foto {
    fotografies {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          Titolo
          slug
          immagini {
            data {
              attributes {
                url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  `
  const { data } = await useAsyncQuery(query)

  </script>
```

I don't know how to iterate nested object. I get the object from Strapi with graphql

This is the data object got from Graphql with the query from Strapi

```
data:Object (Ref)
 fotografies:Object
  __typename:"FotografieEntityResponseCollection"
data:Array[2]
 0:Object
  __typename:"FotografieEntity"
   attributes:Object
    Titolo:"Gnu Etosha"
  __typename:"Fotografie"
    immagini:Object
  __typename:"UploadFileRelationResponseCollection"
data:Array[1]
 0:Object
  slug:"gnu-etosha"
   id:"1"
    1:Object
  __typename:"FotografieEntity"
   attributes:Object
    Titolo:"Rinoceronte bianco"
  __typename:"Fotografie"
    immagini:Object
 __typename:"UploadFileRelationResponseCollection"
  data:Array[1]
   slug:"rinoceronte-bianco"
  id:"2"
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with graphql. If you can show how your `data` object looks like, probably I can help you.

Comment: Can you `JSON.stringify(data, null, '  ')` instead?

Comment: Where I have to set the JSON.stringify? I am not expert

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think it's because you have everything in query nested in each other, heres an example of how an array should usually look if your going to use v-for

```
const users = [
  {
    firstname: "Fred",
    lastName: "Boy",
    email: "abc@t.com",
  },
  {
    firstname: "Tom",
    lastName: "Boy",
    email: "abc@t.com",
  },
  {
    firstname: "Jerry",
    lastName: "Boy",
    email: "abc@t.com",
  },
  {
    firstname: "Sam",
    lastName: "Boy",
    email: "abc@t.com",
  }
```

In this case you have your users who we are going to be doing v-for for, and here is what you will have in the template.

```
<div v-for="user in users" :key="user.firstName">
    <div>
      <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>{{ user.firstname }} {{ user.lastName }}</p>
      <p text-xs">{{ user.email }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So in the above example we are using user.firstname as the key but say if you were using a database as your source it could be something like user.id, or in this case it could also be user.lastname or something like that.

Also when you put your {{ item }} it has to be something like {{ item.id }} or something like that for in your one in the above it's user.firstname otherwise it's going and finding item and I think that might be why it's getting the whole object because your not specifying what you want in there.

The way you've got this set up is a little different to how I've usually seen I usually try to stay pretty close to the example I set up above I think that might be why you are getting problems.
Hope this helped.